# Свойство "files" не существует на vk api search.video

Tags: vkontakte-api

в vk.com/dev/video.search у меня есть это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда я вызываю API, у меня это, свойство "files" не существует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации по методу [`video.search`](https://vk.com/dev/video.search) в колонке `Результат` сказано:

> Если в Вашем приложении используется [прямая авторизация](https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct), возвращается
>   дополнительное поле **files**, содержащее ссылку на файл с видео (если
>   ролик размещен на сервере ВКонтакте) или ссылку на внешний ресурс
>   (если ролик встроен с какого-либо видеохостинга).

Я предполагаю, что у Вас нет возможности использовать прямую авторизацию, так как ([*цитата*](https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct)):

> **Доступ к этому типу авторизации может быть получен только после
>   предварительного согласования с администрацией ВКонтакте.**